# Black view instead of table

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I got a tabbar application.

There is only 2 tabs in the tabbar. First tab is a `NavigationController`, second is a `TableViewController`. Second works perfect, but the the first doesn't.

When i start application, i saw black window. And there is not title on the NavigationBar.

```
self.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Routes";
```

[image]

What's the problem? Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you haven't pushed a view controller to your navigation controller yet. A navigation controller is just a container for another `UIViewController`.

Do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad]

  // Initialize an UIViewController here ...

  [self pushViewController:myRootViewController animated:NO];
}
```